# Do I need the Complete Edition of Horizon Zero Dawn to get all the items?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I have the original *Horizon Zero Dawn* which my mum picked up a garbage sale. While looking at [the Complete Edition of *Horizon Zero Dawn*](https://store.playstation.com/en-au/product/EP9000-CUSA10211_00-HRZCE00000000000) to see what DLC it included to determine if it would be cheaper to rebuy it or just download the DLC for the original it lists

> - Horizon Zero Dawn.
> - The Frozen Wilds expansion.
> - Carja Storm Ranger Outfit and Carja Mighty Bow.
> - Carja Trader Pack.
> - Banuk Trailblazer Outfit and Banuk Culling Bow.
> - Banuk Traveller Pack.
> - Nora Keeper Pack.
> - Digital art book.
> - PS4™ theme.

Now, excluding the Theme and Art Book, looking at [the original game's addons](https://store.playstation.com/en-au/product/EP9000-CUSA01021_00-HRZ0000000000000) it only lists the expansion. However the Complete Edition also says

> Bonus costumes, weapons and item packs are available after downloading Horizon Zero Dawn: Complete Edition update file version 1.45 otherwise they are unlockable through gameplay.

Which makes me wonder if the other items are unique stuff to the complete edition or if they were DLC for the original game which are now removed.

So with the stuff that's listed for the Complete Edition, do i need the Complete Edition of *Horizon Zero Dawn* to get all the items? can i get them at all in the original version?

Answer (score 1):

While the Frozen Wilds can be purchased separately for a small price, you unfortunately would need to purchase the Complete Edition of Horizon Zero Dawn in order to have access to the additional outfits, weapons, and resource packs.

These items, such as the [Carja Storm Ranger](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Carja_Storm_Ranger) or [Banuk Trailblazer](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Banuk_Trailblazer) outfits, were originally obtainable either via pre-order bonus or the purchase of the Digital Deluxe edition, but then later included in the Complete Edition

> [Outfit] is a rare outfit in Horizon Zero Dawn, initially obtainable only by pre-ordering the game or buying a digital deluxe DLC pack, but later released as part of the Complete Edition